# What is the Beltrami differential?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, differential-equations, teichmuller-theory, quasiconformal

Let $R,S$ be Riemann surfaces and $f: R \to S$ an orientation preserving diffeomorphism. Then $f$ determines what is called a **Beltrami differential** denoted by $\mu \frac{d\bar{z}}{dz}$.

Local expression of $\mu$ is clear, however some texts mention that $\mu$ is a $(-1,1)$ form on $R$. What does that mean? More specifically is $\mu$ the section of a vector bundle, which one? Is there a coordinate free definition for $\mu$?

Comment: It's a section of $\omega^{*} \otimes \omega$ where $\omega$ is the canonical bundle. It's determines the deformation of complex structures.

Comment: More precisely, the Kodaira-Spencer map of a first order deformation around a given Riemann surface (i.e, a deformation of an $X$, the special fiber, over $\text{Specan} (\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2))$) is the multiplication by the Beltrami differential. So this gives a coordinate free definition. See for instance, the beginning of http://www.amazon.com/Advances-Moduli-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821821563

Comment: @user40276 Do you mean it is a section of $\omega^* \otimes \bar{\omega}$ where $\omega$ is the canonical bundle. In that case $\omega^*$ is just the tangent bundle. That does make sense.

Comment: Yes, I've forgotten the over line.

Comment: $(-1,1)$ form is a ratio of $(0,1)$ form and a $(1,0)$ form. The definition of Beltrami differential is similar to definition of any other differential. "To each local coordinate it puts a function into correspondence, which transforms in such and such way when we change the local coordinate".